# Calculating Variance in Pytorch on Spatial axis

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, variance

I am trying to calculate variance in Pytorch but unable to do on multiple axis.

I have similar thing done in Tensorflow but unable to do it on Pytorch as torch.var function takes int as dimension instead of axes.
*Below code is channel last code, I expect axes=[2,3]*

```
Lambda(lambda x: tf.nn.moments(x, axes=[1, 2]))
```

For example, if input_dims = (5, 10, 25, 25) then output_dims should be (5,10, 1, 1).

Comment: This feature is being [worked on](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/9703)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is to use `tensor.view()` to flatten all the dimensions that you want to calculate the variance for into one dimension before you apply the `var()` method:

`torch.var(x.view(x.shape[0], x.shape[1], 1, -1,), dim=3, keepdim=True)`

I used `keepdim=True` to keep the dimension that we calculate the variance for to get the desired output shape.

Comment: I tried the code, but results are not accurate when compared with **Numpy** and **TensorFlow** version. Also, your results matches with the link shared by @Coolness.

Comment: Now, it resolves the issue. There is unbiased parameters in variance, which need to be set **False** (default is True). Thanks mate.